# what is the meaning of this sentence in that context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the below link, I have found some text. I don't understanf why the author wrote what she wrote. 
http://www.greenoptimistic.com/fruit-vegetables-taste-europe-america/#.VsK-rPl94gs

the title of article is "Do Fruit and Vegg Taste Better in Europe?"

> Is it true that Europeans get better tastier fruits and vegetables
>   than the Americans? According to science, yes.
>
> Initially, I was a bit hesitant to write this piece for a two main
>   reasons. The first one is the fact that I have never eaten American
>   vegetables, and the second one- I definitely have a lot to say about
>   quality of European vegetables, especially if sold in a supermarket.
>
> But, for certain, the findings of Julia Belluz of Vox triggered my
>   attention. She shares her experience of visiting rural Italy, where
>   she ate the most delicious tomatoes, and then moves on to finding the
>   reasons why Americans do not have such tasty produce.
>
> Now, on one hand, she might be very right. When comparing supermarket
>   American tomatoes, with these small flavorsome ones that she has
>   tried, it must have been quite a shock. The reason is that American
>   supermarkets apparently have regulations on size of tomatoes they
>   sell, meaning that anything smaller than whatever it is on the shelves
>   now, would just not make it.
>
> To go further into tomatoes, scientists have found out that the
>   genetic manipulation that has been done on those particular red and
>   juicy supermarket fruits **(vegetables, depending on which side of this
>   argument you are)**, makes them grow. This growth, however, limits the
>   production of sugars by the plant, and therefore the resulting tomato
>   is pretty looking but tasteless........................

what does she mean by "**(vegetables, depending on which side of this argument you are)**"?

Comment: Grizzly has answered correctly. Worth noting that there should be an "on" at the end. I suspect the writer is trying to avoid ending the sentence with a preposition, and erroneously thinks that the "on" earlier does the job, but of course that is part of the verb "depend on". As such, the sentence should be "vegetables, depending on which side of this argument you are on" or, for the pedantic, "vegetables, depending on on which side of the argument you are".

Comment: Knew I was right about that ''on'' at the end.

Comment: No, there is already an "on" in the middle of the sentence: "(vegetables, depending on which side of this argument you are)"

Answer (score 2):

Tomatoes has been long discussed as whether they are fruits or vegetables. Although they are registered as fruits, common people like me classify them as vegetables.

...supermarket fruits;here the author classifies tomatoes as 'fruits'.

Then the author opens a parentheses and writes 'vegetables; depending on which side of the **argument** you are'.

That argument is the discussion of tomatoes whether they are fruits or vegetables.

Here is the wikipedia page for tomatoes:
[Tomato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato)
I quote two sentences from that page;

> The tomato (see pronunciation) is the edible, often red berry-type
>   fruit of the nightshade Solanum lycopersicum,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato)[2] commonly known as
>   a tomato plant.
>
> While tomatoes are botanically and scientifically the berry-type
>   fruits of the tomato plant,[7] they can also be considered a culinary
>   vegetable, causing some confusion

Comment: Thanks to both of you. But, those explanations clear only a part of my confusion. The ARGUMENT isn't about whether tomato is a fruit or a vegetable.  It is about whether fruits and vegetables in Europe really taste better than the ones in America or not.

Comment: Ummmm not exactly. That argument in the parenthesis is  the argument that people have been in for a very long time; whether tomatoes are fruit or vegetables. However the main argument in the text is of course whether fruits and vegetables in Europe really taste better than the ones in America or not as you said.